# How do I connect to the session bus daemon on OS X?

Tags: node.js, dbus

I've got dbus running on OS X and I can send messages via C. Now I'm trying to set up node-dbus inside my node.js server, but it's complaining because I haven't specified a server address. I didn't have to specify one for sending a message in the C++ code, so how do I get the address?

My server was invoked with

```
dbus-daemon --nofork --session
```

By the way, I just learned that abstract sockets aren't supported on OS X, and so I'll have to contend with the dbus-native dependency on abstract-socket, but I'll still need to figure out how to get at the session bus.

In my C++ code I'm just able to get the session bus:

```
::dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SESSION, &error);
```

I haven't been able to verify that a message is actually being sent, but it reports no errors (if the daemon is not running, it does report an error, indicating that it's finding the daemon).

After a little more poking around, I found that my daemon has this socket open:

```
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.jwK0ehYjCd/unix_domain_listener
```

So I tried this:

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.jwK0ehYjCd/unix_domain_listener
```

This allowed it to get further, but it gave me this error (which might be due to the problems with abstract sockets, I'm not sure):

```
connect deprecated multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy, formidable) npm module instead node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:56:20
connect deprecated limit: Restrict request size at location of read node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:86:15
connect deprecated methodOverride: use method-override npm module instead config/initializers/30_middleware.js:16:20
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1129:14)
    at listen (net.js:1155:10)
    at net.js:1253:9
    at dns.js:85:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried executing your `node` script as superuser? `sudo node etc.js`

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference. Moreover, the dbus daemon was started under my user, not root. When I had originally started it as root, my C++ app couldn't find it (when launched under my username).